# Failing to compile ASP.NET Web API with MSBuild giving a MSB3021 error

Tags: c#, msbuild

`enter code here`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cp8G.png)

I'm having a problem when trying to compile and build an ASP.NET Web API project targeting .NET6.0. For some reason MSBuild is failing with the given error. I tried to change the access permissions for both /obj and /bin folders but I'm still getting the same error. However, this only happens when I try to build the project in a Debug mode, and it's working perfectly fine in Release mode. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: That error (please put it in the question as text rather than as an image) typically means that the .exe you're trying to build is already running..

Answer (score 0):

Searching in the other stackoverflow questions (the same issue for net core 6 razor pages), it seems that deleting the bin and obj folders, and rebuilding your solution works. And also restarting your computer seems to work. I still have this issue even though i have tried both solutions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).